# Python: Alternative to quasi random sequences

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hey I have the following problem. I have a large parameter space. In my case I have like 10 dimensions. But to simplify lets assume I have 3 variables x1,x2 and x3. They are discrete numbers from 1 to 10. Now i create all possible parameter combinations and want to use them for postprocessing. In my real case that are too many combinatons. So I want to do a quasi random sequence search to reduce the search space. But the the combinations in the search space should cover it as good as possible. (uniform distributed). I want to prevent the parameter combination to Cluster in the search space, it should Cover the whole search space as good as possible. I need that to find preferences of the parameter combiantions in the processing of the parameters. There a many approaches to do that, like Haton, Hammersley or Sobol sequences. But they are not working for discrete numbers. One package which do quasi random sequences is chaospy. If i round the numbers of the sequences, variable numbers of each variable will occur more than once in the different variable combinations. That is not what I want. I want that every variable number only occurs Once and the variables are uniformly distributed in the search space.  Is there a possibility to create from the beginning a random multi dimensional set of variable combination, in which every variable just appears once? For example In a two dimensional grid 10x10 one possible combination would be the diagonal. Of course in 3 dimensions I would need 100 combinations to Cover all Parameter value,

**Lets have an simplified example with three variables from 1-10 with Sobol Sequence:**

```
import numpy as np
import chaospy as cp

#Create a Joint distributuon of the three varaibles, which ranges going from 1 to 10
distribution2 = cp.J(cp.Uniform(1, 10),cp.Uniform(1, 10),cp.Uniform(1, 10))

#Create 10 numbers in the variable space
samplesSobol = distribution2.sample(10, rule="S")

#Transpose the array to get the variable combinations in subarrays
sobolPointsTranspose = np.transpose(samplesSobol)
```

Example Output:

```
[[ 7.89886475  6.34649658  4.8336792 ]
 [ 5.64886475  4.09649658  2.5836792 ]
 [ 1.14886475  8.59649658  7.0836792 ]
 [ 1.21917725  5.01055908  2.5133667 ]
 [ 5.71917725  9.51055908  7.0133667 ]
 [ 7.96917725  2.76055908  9.2633667 ]
 [ 3.46917725  7.26055908  4.7633667 ]
 [ 4.59417725  1.63555908  5.8883667 ]
 [ 9.09417725  6.13555908  1.3883667 ]
 [ 6.84417725  3.88555908  3.6383667 ]]
```

Now here every variable number is unique but the Output is not discrete. I can round it and get:

```
[[  8.   6.   5.]
 [  6.   4.   3.]
 [  1.   9.   7.]
 [  1.   5.   3.]
 [  6.  10.   7.]
 [  8.   3.   9.]
 [  3.   7.   5.]
 [  5.   2.   6.]
 [  9.   6.   1.]
 [  7.   4.   4.]]
```

Now the problem is, that for example 1 occurs twice in the first dimension or 4 in the second or 7 in the third dimension.

Comment: _the search space..._ What is this? And ppl on SO want to see your code first... show what you have and what output you are expecting to get...

Comment: You need to tell us more about your problem, and what you are trying to achieve There is a huge number of ways to *solve* your problem the way you describe it that will probably not be useful at all. Why can numbers not repeat itself? Is this only true for each single parameter, or also depending on each other?

Comment: I actually think seeing the code is going to make this question harder to answer.  That said, more clarity around the problem description is required to give an answer.

Comment: *"4 variables x1,x2,x3 and x4. They are discrete numbers from 1 to 10."*  This is the search space, correct?  That's 10000 possible points.  What are you doing with these that makes 10000 "too many"?  Or is that just a small example, and you are really interested in a much bigger space?

Comment: So, do you want to generate a of quadruples where every value only occurs once? An algorithm to do that shouldn't be too hard. And you won't need chaospy for it.

Comment: Yeah would be a possibility, but I need a way to control that the variables in the search space are uniformly distributed and Cover the search space as good as possible

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late answer so I assume is no longer relevant to the Original Poster but I came across the post whilst trying to find an existing implementation of what I describe below.

It sounds like you are looking for something like a Latin Hypercube: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling. 
Essentially if I have n variables and I want 10 samples then the range of each variable is split into 10 intervals and the possible values for each variable are (e.g.) the middle points of each interval. A Latin hypercube algorithm picks samples at random in such a way that each of the 10 values for each variable appears only once. The example in Warren's answer is an example of a Latin Hypercube.

This doesn't help to cover the search space as well as possible (or in other words to check if the design is space filling). There is a criterion from Morris and Mitchell's 1995 paper Exploratory designs for computational experiments which calculates how space filling a sample is by looking at the distance between points. You can create a large number of different Latin Hypercube Designs and then use the criterion to choose the best, or take an initial design and manipulate it to give a better design. The latter is implemented in the algorithm here: https://github.com/1313e/e13Tools/blob/master/e13tools/sampling/lhs.py 
They give some examples in the code, e.g. for 5 points and 2 variables:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
lhd(5, 2, method='fixed')
```

returns something like

```
array([[ 0.5 ,  0.75],
       [ 0.25,  0.25],
       [ 0.  ,  1.  ],
       [ 0.75,  0.5 ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.  ]])
```

This will give the Latin Hypercube scaled on the interval [0, 1] so you would need to unscale to the range of your parameters using, for example

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Here's an example of one of the outputs I get when I run the above code:
[image]

This one is pretty good at space-filling according to the Morris-Mitchell criterion.

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there a possibility to create from the beginning a random multi dimensional set of variable combination, in which every variable just appears once?"*  For this to work, each variable must have the same number of possible values.  In your examples this number is 10, so I'll use that.

One way to generate the random points is to stack random permutations of range(10).  Like this, for example, with three variables:

```
In [180]: np.column_stack([np.random.permutation(10) for _ in range(3)])
Out[180]: 
array([[6, 6, 4],
       [9, 2, 0],
       [0, 4, 3],
       [5, 9, 5],
       [2, 8, 7],
       [1, 1, 9],
       [8, 3, 8],
       [3, 5, 1],
       [4, 0, 2],
       [7, 7, 6]])
```

Comment: Yeah would be a possibility, but I need a way to control that the variables in the search space are uniformly distributed and Cover the search space as good as possible

Comment: Please edit the question to include that information.

Comment: How would you control a uniform distribution? What does that exactly mean? What exactly do you want to stop from happening?

Comment: That means, that I want to prevent the parameter combination to Cluster in the search space, it should Cover the whole search space as good as possible. I need that to find preferences of the parameter combiantions in the processing of the parameters

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, no value in a dimension may repeat. That means that your search space is constrained to 10 entries, if the value of each parameter can only go up to 10. You can't control a distribution with only 10 entries if you only control within one dimension. Or do you also control for any value over all dimensions as well?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is restricted to ne range of the parameter. Therefore maybe it would be useful to give like a covereparameter. So if the values are restricted to 10 entries in a room of 10x10x10 you can say it has a coverage of 3. Then a value would in one dimension would appear 3 times. But all combinations then should cover the search space as good as possible

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives a function that generates a list of 4-value lists such that
[a, b, c, d] are natural numbers between 1 and 10. In each set, the parameters may only take any value exactly once.

```
import random

def generate_random_sequences(num_params=4, seed=0)
    random.seed(seed)
    value_lists = [[val for val in range(1, 11)] for _ in range(num_params)]
    for values in value_lists:
        random.shuffle(values)
    ret = [[] for _ in range(num_params)]
    for value_idx in range(10):
        for param_idx in range(num_params):
            ret[param_idx].append(value_lists[param_idx][value_idx])
    return ret
```

I just saw that Warren's answer using numpy is way superior, and you use numpy already anyway. Still submitting this one as a pure python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

(Years later) 10 points in 3d with no dups in columns, no dups in rows, and plots in RGB color space --

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""In: 10 x 10 x 10 cube at integers [0 0 0] .. [9 9 9]
    a profit / loss function f() at these 1000 points
Want: 10 points, 10 x 3, with each column containing 0 1 2 .. 9 exactly once
    and average f( first N points ) -> average f( all 1000 ),
    see wikipedia Sobol_sequence.

The behavior of average f( N points ) will depend *strongly* on f() --
how smooth, how uniformly spaced the coordinates are, permutable xyz yxz ...
For example if f() is linear, its min / max are at the corners of the cube.
"""

import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

print( 80 * "▄" )
print( __doc__ )

#...............................................................................
A0 = np.array([
    [3, 5, 7],
    [9, 0, 1],
    [0, 9, 8],
    [8, 1, 0],
    [1, 8, 2],
    [7, 2, 3],
    [2, 7, 9],
    [6, 3, 4],
    [4, 6, 5],
    [5, 4, 6],
])

    # plot 10 colors in RGB space, then in permuted GBR BRG --
for roll in [0, 1, 2]:
    A = np.roll( A0, roll, axis=1 )
    sns.palplot( A / 9 )
```